# package quotchap vertical space before \chapter*

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters

I use the package `quotchap` it is very nice. But for the star chapters, if I use quotation, there is no space between quotation and the title of the chapter. I tried, but witout any success, to add `\vspace` or `\bigskip` or `minipage`, but nothing works.

Do you have any idea?
here a file

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{natbib}%authoryear[round]
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Pour utiliser les lettres accentues
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[grey]{quotchap}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{savequote}[8cm]
Oh

le ciel est gris

il fait pas beau
\medskip

Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pou
\end{savequote}

  \chapter*{Introduction\markboth{INTRODUCTION}{INTRODUCTION}}
  \lipsum

\end{document}
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The following redefinition of `\@makechapterhead` (as (re)defined in `quotchap.sty`) will give you the same spacing for numbered and unnumbered chapters:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{natbib}%authoryear[round]
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Pour utiliser les lettres accentues
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[grey]{quotchap}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
  \chapterheadstartvskip%
  {\size@chapter{\sectfont\raggedleft
    {\chapnumfont
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne%
        \if@mainmatter\thechapter\else\phantom{\thechapter}%
      \fi\else\phantom{\thechapter}\fi
      \par\nobreak}%
    {\raggedleft\advance\leftmargin10em\interlinepenalty\@M #1\par}}
  \nobreak\chapterheadendvskip}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{savequote}[8cm]
Oh

le ciel est gris

il fait pas beau
\medskip

Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pou
\end{savequote}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you really, it is of great help, I hope to answer to other if I could! And I add : it WORKS even in the big document !!!

Comment: @user20294 You're welcome! Don't forget that, after a sensible wait for possible alternative answers, you can accept the answer that best solved your problems by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 0):

I have added \vspace{-3cm} which allows a nice repartition between the quotation and the star chapter. If you do not put this vspace, the star chapter is very low on the page.

```
\makeatletter  
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
\chapterheadstartvskip%
{\size@chapter{\sectfont\raggedleft
  {\chapnumfont
   \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne%
    \if@mainmatter\thechapter\else\phantom{\thechapter}%
  \fi\else\vspace{-3cm}\phantom{\thechapter}\fi
  \par\nobreak}%
{\raggedleft\advance\leftmargin10em\interlinepenalty\@M #1\par}}
\nobreak\chapterheadendvskip}}
\makeatother
```